# How to merge two dataframes with not identical columns like this way? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes look like this (real are bigger):

DF1:

| Alliances_names | Value1 |
| --- | --- |
| cgc inc/nshow ltd/noracle inc | 500 |
| steam/nsoap jv | NaN |
| saints bd | 8 |
| watrloo jv/ncgc inc/nflow inc | 19 |

DF2:

| Company | Number1 | Number2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| steam | 15 | y |
| soap jv | 2000 | n |
| cgc inc | 4565 | n |
| show ltd | 1 | n |
| flow inc | 1111 | y |
| watrloo jv | 6756 | n |

I have to merge these two dataframes with alliances and company columns. If it is company in  alliance I have to add this information to the row. (There is /n delimiter between companies in DF1)
The result should be like this:

| Alliances_names | Value1 | Company | Number1 | Number2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cgc inc/nshowltd/noracle inc | 500 | cgc inc | 4565 | n |
| cgc inc/nshowltd/noracle inc | 500 | show ltd | 1 | n |
| steam/nsoap jv | NaN | steam | 15 | y |
| steam/nsoap jv | NaN | soap jv | 2000 | n |
| saints bd | 8 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| watrloo jv/ncgc inc/nflow inc | 19 | watrloo jv | 6756 | n |
| watrloo jv/ncgc inc/nflow inc | 19 | cgc inc | 4565 | n |
| watrloo jv/ncgc inc/nflow inc | 19 | flow inc | 1111 | y |

I need to duplicate alliances name for every company in this.
I tried to separate companies in "alliances name" and make another column with lists of companies in every cell, but "isin" didn't work good with it and I couldn't megre dataframes with duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a separate column (called "Company") with individual company names using [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html).
2. [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.DataFrame.merge) the two DataFrames on the "Company" column.

```
df1["Company"] = df1["Alliances_names"].str.split("/n")
df1 = df1.explode("Company")
output = df1.merge(df2, on="Company", how="left")

>>> output
                 Alliances_names  Value1     Company  Number1 Number2
0  cgc inc/nshow ltd/noracle inc   500.0     cgc inc   4565.0       n
1  cgc inc/nshow ltd/noracle inc   500.0    show ltd      1.0       n
2  cgc inc/nshow ltd/noracle inc   500.0  oracle inc      NaN     NaN
3                 steam/nsoap jv     NaN       steam     15.0       y
4                 steam/nsoap jv     NaN     soap jv   2000.0       n
5                      saints bd     8.0   saints bd      NaN     NaN
6  watrloo jv/ncgc inc/nflow inc    19.0  watrloo jv   6756.0       n
7  watrloo jv/ncgc inc/nflow inc    19.0     cgc inc   4565.0       n
8  watrloo jv/ncgc inc/nflow inc    19.0    flow inc   1111.0       y
```

###### Edit:

To only keep the rows where all Alliances_names are in `df2`, you can do:

```
output = output[output["Alliances_names"].str.split("/n").map(set(df2["Company"]).issuperset)]

>>> output
                 Alliances_names  Value1     Company  Number1 Number2
3                 steam/nsoap jv     NaN       steam     15.0       y
4                 steam/nsoap jv     NaN     soap jv   2000.0       n
6  watrloo jv/ncgc inc/nflow inc    19.0  watrloo jv   6756.0       n
7  watrloo jv/ncgc inc/nflow inc    19.0     cgc inc   4565.0       n
8  watrloo jv/ncgc inc/nflow inc    19.0    flow inc   1111.0       y
```

Comment: One more question.
Is there a way to delete alliances from "alliances_names" if there is not all alliances in df2?
In result there will be only  steam/nsoap jv with duplicates and watrloo jv/ncgc inc/nflow inc with duplicates.

Comment: thanks! but it works strange in dataset with 164000 rows. It removes some rows with alliances that have all companies in "company", I don't know why :( 
I noticed this when I checked some data manually.

Comment: Shouldn't - the logic doesn't depend on the size of your dataframe. Could be your actual data (spelling differences or leading/trailing spaces etc.).